# Haskell - ghci - why type of 1 is Num?

Tags: haskell, ghci

Can anyone please explain why,

```
Prelude> let a = 1
Prelude> :type a
a :: Integer
Prelude> :type 1
1 :: Num a => a
```

Why a is an `Integer` and `1` is a `Num`?
I can understand why `1+2` would be `Num`. But why `1`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is just an artifact of how the type inference works in the interactive prompt. All numeric literals are polymorphic for any `a` that is an instance of the `Num` typeclass, but in the GHCi prompt any `let` binding without an explicit signature is inferred with a monomorphic type (more details [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction)).

You can make GHCi infer the more general type by setting

```
Prelude> :set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction 
Prelude> let a = 1
Prelude> :type a
a :: Num a => a
```

Answer (score 5):

That `1` is just a general `Num` instance, not any particular one, is perfectly reasonable and one of the great things about Haskell's type classes. This allows you to use integral literals in any context from actual integers to complex numbers to infinite-dimensional Hilbert-space operators, never having to bother about conversions or horribly ugly "`7.0`" (or worse) literals that you find so often in other languages.

A better question would be: *why is `a` not also such a general instance, but a concrete `Integer` type*? That has to do with the [dreaded monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction). As shown by shang, you can switch that off; but in GHCi it's actually sometimes convenient to have the compiler make fixed choices for you, because you usually don't want to bother writing type signatures there.

In Haskell source files, the monomorphism restriction is basically just an artifact, as the Wiki article says nobody is really content with it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the indepth explanation. Accepted Shang's because of timing. Thanks.

Comment: The 1 being treated as a Num a => a doesn't have to do with type classes as much as the implicit fromInteger that's inserted by the compiler. One could imagine something similar for string literals -- and that's your OverloadedStrings pragma.

Comment: @kqr: but `fromInteger` wouldn't work this way if Haskell implemented the overloading through something like casting in OO / dynamic languages, instead of type classes. That's what I mean.

Comment: Sure, it's a combination effort, I guess.